# Creating Hyper-V VM fails with failed to load a library error

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

I am trying to create a Ubuntu 18 VM with Hyper-V under Windows 10 Enterprise.

In particular, I want to increase the disk space.

I get an error pop-up box with the following message.

```
Failed to load a library required by Hyper-V Manager. To resolve the problem, close Server Manager, then open Server Manager again, and then open Hyper-V Manager again.
```

I am running Hyper-V quick create as an Administrator.

The Hyper-V Manager is already running.

I have tried closing and re-opening Hyper-V Manager, but still get the same error.

Hyper-V Manager gives version as 10.0.17134.1

Windows 10 gives version as 1803 (OS Build 1714.1967)

Answer (score 0):

This was due to configuring more than one SCSI controller entry. In theory, this should not prevent the VM from being created, but nevertheless it does.